# Problem with creation of wallet using Javascript

Tags: wallet, nft, mint, vscode, java

Im using linux-Ubuntu in the WSL of the Windows 10.
I have installed Cardano-node and Cardano-cli. Node v14 (latest stable version) ghc 8.10.6

Im trying to create a wallet but on this command:
`node src/create-wallet.js`

I get this error:

```
const paymentVkey = options.paymentVkey
                                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'paymentVkey' of undefined
    at CardanocliJs.addressBuild (/home/marcelolinux/minter3/node_modules/cardanocli-js/index.js:316:33)
    at createWallet (/home/marcelolinux/minter3/src/create-wallet.js:7:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/marcelolinux/minter3/src/create-wallet.js:11:1)
```

Im following [this](https://github.com/armada-alliance/cardano-minter) (maybe) out of date tutorial.

I'have tryed with ghc 8.10.4 , also tryed configure the testnet but did'nt work also.

Can anyone help me to Mint Nft's using Javascript? I'm needing it for my final project of a course of Web Development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cardanocli-js) for cardanocli-js and found that you need to pass an options object to the AddressBuild method.

```
const createWallet = (account) => {
  cardano.addressKeyGen(account);
  cardano.stakeAddressKeyGen(account);
  cardano.stakeAddressBuild(account);
  cardano.addressBuild(account);
  return cardano.wallet(account);
};

createWallet("ADAPI");
```

needs to be altered to include an options object per the documentation.

It should be altered to be;

```
const createWallet = (account) => {
  const payment = cardano.addressKeyGen(account);
  const stake = cardano.stakeAddressKeyGen(account);
  cardano.stakeAddressBuild(account);
  cardano.addressBuild(account, {
    paymentVkey: payment.vkey,
    stakeVkey: stake.vkey,
  });
  return cardano.wallet(account);
};

createWallet("ADAPI");
```

This worked for me. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me also. You Rock dude.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having the same problem on window using cardano-node-1.29.0-win64.  cardanocli-js node module has issue on windows doesn't know how to create folder correctly, I need to modified "index.js" file.  After fixing all that I finally run into the same problem you are facing.

For ubuntu, I got some weird problems not able to access my cardano-cli even I have it in my path, node is having trouble accessing.

Comment: I tried to build it manually by passing in skey and vkey files but no luck still, any help would be appreciated.